# Tableau: How to select data points in map to filter data?

Tags: tableau

I would like to filter my data to only present observations taking place in Berlin (where data points are concentrated in the image below). How can this be achieved? The only geographical information my data provides is the coordinates of the start and end of a trip.

I attempted to select the data hoping I could group it but no grouping option comes up when right-clicking...

[image]

Comment: You should be able to simpy select the data points and select the `Keep Only` option, see also [this official Tableau page on filtering data](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/filtering.htm#select-to-keep-or-exclude-data-points-in-your-view).

Comment: No keep only or exclude option shows up when performing the selection and hovering. All I can do is view the selected points in a table.

Answer (score 2):

Answer: for filter by a city, country or zone:

1. Drag and Drop the city field in the Filters zone ( Up - Left)
2. Right Click in the city dimension and Filter by zone
3. Select the zones that you want.
4. Apply

I can't see your tables so I can't help you filtering your data. I need to know about your dimensions and measures but I can guide to you with a example of filtering data my a sector.

The latitudes and longitudes are generate automatically by city in the tables, so you only have to drag and drow city to your Filters section (Also you can filter by latitude and longitudes filtering measures).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]